# Z-index no NiceScroll

Tags: jquery, plugin, rolamento, z-index

Ao aplicar este script para suavização do scroll (o nicescroll) ocorre do mesmo ficar sob alguns itens do site com o Z-index maior. Onde posso por um Z-index nele para que sobreponha este itens do site?

```
$(document).ready(

  function() { 

    $("html").niceScroll();

  }

);
```

Comment: Teria como você fazer um exemplo funcional? Você pode [edit] sua pergunta e usar o trecho de código (CTRL+M)  ou criar no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
$('div.nicescroll-rails').css('z-index',valor);
```